# How to pass a variable to the argument of arcname of zipfile.write method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I'm using python's zipfile library.　(python=3.10)

I want to specify arcname in the zf.write method and save it.
If you specify a fixed string for arcname, it works fine, but you cannot specify a string that contains variables.

The pseudo code is shown below.
When I run this code
pages \ page {i} .xml is saved in the archive. This is not the behavior I want.

```
i=1
archive_path = 'test.zip'
with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_path, 'a') as zf:
            zf.write(f"page{i}.xml", arcname=f'pages\page{i}.xml')
```

We can save without any problem by directly specifying the file name without using format.

```
i=1
archive_path = 'test.zip'
with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_path, 'a') as zf:
            zf.write(f"page{i}.xml", arcname='pages\page1.xml')
```

Is there a way to give a variable to arcname?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot pass value "i" in this line: `zf.write(f"page{i}.xml", arcname=f'pages\page{}.xml')`
You should try: `zf.write(f"page{i}.xml", arcname=f'pages\page{i}.xml')`

Comment: It was a misspelling in this question text. 
In the actual program, "zf.write (f" page {i} .xml ", arcname = f'pages \ page {i} .xml')" is used, but it does not work well.